# adding row to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When i use this line of code row is getting added in table

```
$('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>Added here</td></tr>');
```

but when i use it for this it is not working

```
$('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work new" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=''){this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work5" name="other_work5" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_workn']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name5" type="text" id="client_name5" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name5" type="text" id="firm_name5" size="40"/></td></tr>');
```

where is the mistake?

Comment: why you have 2 onclick handlers for input in your code?

Comment: and it's better to use some IDE or editor which will highlight your errors, to prevent such simple cases

Comment: actually i am new to coding ,so can you suggest any such good editor,because in my editor it didn't show me this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your single quotes. Try this:

```
$('#preq > tbody:last').append('' +
  '<tr>' +
    '<td>' +
      '<input title="Enter Kind Of work new" readonly="readonly" ' +
        'onclick="if(this.value!=\'\'){this.value=\'\';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work5" name="other_work5" type="text" size="30" ' +
        'onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_workn']).'"'; } ?>>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
      '<input name="client_name5" type="text" id="client_name5" size="40"/>' +
    '</td>' +
    '<td>' +
      '<input name="firm_name5" type="text" id="firm_name5" size="40"/>' +
    '</td>' +
  '</tr>'
);
```

Please also note that the php will be executed before the html is appended since PHP is server side...

Answer (score 2):

#### Unescaped string:

`$('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work new" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!='')`
`--------------------------------------------^
{this.value='';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work5"`
`------------^`
`name="other_work5" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_workn']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name5" type="text" id="client_name5" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name5" type="text" id="firm_name5" size="40"/></td></tr>');`

Just escape them using `\'` and you are good!

#### Working one:

> `$('#preq > tbody:last').append('<tr><td><input title="Enter Kind Of work new" readonly="readonly" onclick="if(this.value!=\'\'){this.value=\'\';opendrop();}else{opendrop();}" id="other_work5" name="other_work5" type="text" size="30" onclick="opendrop()"  <?php if (isset($errors)) { echo 'value="'.htmlentities(@$_POST['other_workn']).'"'; } ?>></td><td><input name="client_name5" type="text" id="client_name5" size="40"/></td><td><input name="firm_name5" type="text" id="firm_name5" size="40"/></td></tr>');`

Comment: Introducing another programming language layer for something so mudane is like exterminating ants with nuclear warheads. This will work, but makes everything unneccessarily complicated. It also is a perfect rip-off of the code of MrXenotype.

Comment: @MartinHohenberg I answered this before him! FYIP!

Answer (score 1):

Unescaped single quotes inside your code surrounded by single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The first single quote (') in

```
"if(this.value!='')
```

closes the string opened with

```
append('
```

Escape all single quotes in the string you want to append.